# Matching multiple rows of one Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, match

I've got a big Matrix (over 10.000.000 rows) filled with Transactions and the Columns:
TransactionDate, Verified ("VERIFIED" or NULL), UUID (could come up multiple times), n_UUID (how many times this UUID had a transaction), a journey_UUID (could also come up multiple times) and n_journey (the number of transactions in this Journey. Here is an excerpt:

```
"TransactionDate" "Verified" "UUID" "n_UUID" "journey_UUID" "n_journey"
2014-10-04 23:18:58     ""     247538     118     679237     10
2014-10-04 23:19:04     ""     620831     79     1221991     5
2014-10-04 23:19:05     ""     247538     118     679237     10
2014-10-04 23:19:16     ""     103757     52     377034     1
2014-10-04 23:19:17     ""     23031     177     113316     1
2014-10-04 23:19:25     "VERIFIED"     1539737     1     2195168     1
2014-10-04 23:19:25     ""     1539738     2     2195169     1
2014-10-04 23:19:25     ""     620831     79     1221991     5
2014-10-04 23:19:33     ""     247538     118     679237     10
2014-10-04 23:19:33     ""     1539739     11     2195171     11
2014-10-04 23:19:34     ""     954364     50     1565701     7
2014-10-04 23:19:37     "VERIFIED"     197254     56     575615     1
2014-10-04 23:19:38     ""     1539740     1     2195172     1
2014-10-04 23:19:40     ""     620831     79     1221991     5
2014-10-04 23:19:41     ""     954364     50     1565701     7
2014-10-04 23:19:42     ""     500642     7     1070762     1
2014-10-04 23:19:42     ""     1539741     1     2195173     1
2014-10-04 23:19:43     ""     1539742     1     2195174     1
2014-10-04 23:19:43     ""     23322     162     116724     10
2014-10-04 23:19:45     ""     247538     118     679237     10
2014-10-04 23:19:48     "VERIFIED"     620831     79     1221991     5
2014-10-04 23:19:52     ""     247538     118     679237     10
2014-10-04 23:19:58     ""     481173     55     1047024     1
2014-10-04 23:20:02     ""     620831     79     1221991     5
2014-10-04 23:20:22     ""     1539743     1     2195175     1
2014-10-04 23:20:33     ""     612282     17     1212634     1
2014-10-04 23:20:38     ""     1539739     11     2195171     11
2014-10-04 23:20:40     ""     1539744     2     2195176     1
2014-10-04 23:20:42     ""     1539745     1     2195178     1
2014-10-04 23:20:45     ""     1539746     14     2195179     3
```

I want to find out how many of the transactions with n_UUID "X" are verified, same thing for n_journey. I also want to find out if the order has an influence (via TransactionDate).

Until now, I split the Matrix by n_journey (or n_UUID):

```
Journey4 <- (Example[grep("4" , n_journey)])
```

ordered it by TransactionDate and journey_UUID afterwards, numbered it (in this case till 4) and split it via this number:

```
Journey4$NR <- 1:(Journey4$n_journey)
GSfirst <- Journey4[grep("\\b1\\b" , NR)]
GSsecond  <- Journey4[grep("\\b2\\b" , NR)]
GSthird <- Journey4[grep("\\b3\\b" , NR)]
GSfourth  <- Journey4[grep("\\b4\\b" , NR)]
```

After that, I joined it by journey_UUID. 
This actually works, but it looks more like a workaround to me.

The Problem is that its not really automatic. I have to change the Parameters by myself everytime I want to change something.

My Question is: Is it possible to automatically match the Matrix by UUID on itself? So that every line means one UUID and the Transactions are lined up?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming that your data is saved in a dataframe called d. You can use simply `d[ d$Verified %in% "VERIFIED", ]` to get all verified transactions.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output here?

Comment: @Jimbou Why not just `d[ d$Verified == "VERIFIED", ]`?

Comment: @Jaap I use `%in%` instead of `==` because there are sometimes problems with missing data. Tried to avoid these although there are no NAs in the example file.

Answer (score 0):

given that your dataframe "df" has the columns named: TransactionDate, Verified, UUID, n_UUID, journey_UUID, n_journey you can subset df by "Verified" column as follows:

```
df.new <- subset(df, df$Verified == "Verified")
```

I didn't really understand what you want to do by: "I also want to find out if the order has an influence (via TransactionDate)."

hope it clarifies at least something